# I'm trying to make RLE code withouth success

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make function of "Run Length Encoding" and I'm stuck in the middle.

For example, I have the string: `"RRRTTTFBB"` and I'm trying to separate this to this kind of array: `["RRR", "TTT", "F", "BB"]`.

I only managed to put to items in 1 key of the array like so: `["RR" "R" "TT" "T" ....]`

I've tried to do it with a while loop, for a loop, if/else, switch, but I can't figure what I am doing wrong.

```
function rleFunc(str) {
  let newArr = [];
  const strTrim = str.trim();
  const strUp = strTrim.toUpperCase();
  const arr = strUp.split("");
  const arrLength = arr.length;
  // Anyone has idea what to put here?? I'm lost
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the version you tried with `for` loop (seems the most appropriate for the task) and precise what was wrong? Remember that SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I didn't asked for free coding. the new array is just part of my proccess. + I don't have it anymore because I deleted and tried many things!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to use a regular expression with `.match` to get the result you're after:

```js
const str = "RRRTTTFBB";
console.log(str.match(/(.)\1*/g));
```

This works due to the expression:

- `(.)`: Means group any character
- `\1*`: Means use the previously grouped character and match zero more occurrences of it
- `/g`: Means repeat this pattern for the entire string (not just the first occurrence)

Answer (score 1):

```
 const result = [];
 let count = 1;

 const input = "RRRTTTFBB";

 for(let index = 1; index < input.length; index++) {
    if(input[index] !== input[index - 1]) {
      result.push(input[index - 1].repeat(count));
      count = 1;
     } else count++;
 }
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: 'Try' is never the answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
function group(arr) {
  const groups = [arr[0]]

  for (const char of arr.slice(1)) {
    const last = groups.length - 1

    if (char === groups[last][0]) {
      groups[last] += char
    } else {
      groups.push(char)
    }
  }
  
  return groups
}

console.log(group('RRRTTTFBB'))
```

Comment: @JonasWilms few tweaks were required indeed. Revisiting helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use regular expression for trivial tasks or unless you have to. Also if the string being evaluated is user input. It can lead to blocking operation in node. Read up on it here :https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

```js
arr="RRRRTTHHHJJJHHJ"
    const map = new Map;
    for (const char of arr.split('')) {
  
    if (map.has(char)) {

    map.set(char, map.get(char)+char)
    } else {
    map.set(char, char)
    }
    }
    console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Comment: any comments on the downvote would be very helpful.